# How to get a clicked elements from the series of looped elements?

Tags: html, video, frontend, html5-video, ejs

I have videos that looped using ejs template engine, and I want to handle click event when a certain video elements is targeted.

I want to get a clicked video when a user clicks a video in a loop.

Take codes below as an example:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<100; i++ { %>
<video>
<source src="assets/video.mp4">
<video>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for click events on the video and look at the source.

One thing to be aware of - the currentSrc is set after the metadata is loaded. I suspect this will be ok for your use case, but if not you can wait for the 'onloadeddata' event before allowing ehe click function.

```js
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');

    videoElement.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
      console.log(`Clicked` + videoElement.currentSrc);
      videoElement.play(); //To continue playing the video
      })
```

```html
<video autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: That's true, but how if those video are more that one, that works on a single video, and I want to play only a clicked video from the lost on those hundred videos looped by using ejs template.

Comment: The above is plain javascript so should work anywhere, including inside your loop. It will give you the source value of whichever video the user clicked.